# Spring Security returning 302 for all static content configured with security none

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot

I was using this security configuration:

```
<security:http pattern="/app/.*" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/assets/.*" security="none" />

<security:http jaas-api-provision="true" request-matcher="regex" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="defaultLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index\.html.*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/.*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="LAST" ref="myTokenFilter"/>
    <security:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="defaultSuccessHandler"
                         login-processing-url="/login"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="defaultAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    <security:logout delete-cookies="user" success-handler-ref="defaultLogoutHandler" logout-url="/logout"/>
</security:http>
```

The application works fine using it but there is a performance issue because the security none configuration is wrong (I am using regex pattern while the default is ant) and myTokenFilter call a rest service more times than I need.
I correct the config like below:

```
<security:http request-matcher="regex" pattern="/app/.*" security="none" />
<security:http request-matcher="regex" pattern="/assets/.*" security="none" />
```

Now the filter works correctly but the application doesn't work anymore. All static request return 302 and redirect to logout. I change my logout url for avoid redirect back to portal and I saw this in browser.

Old config (working).

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjlxO.jpg)

New config:

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKhMS.jpg)

Beyond the logout, I note the browser recognize js files like json with no reason.

My application use angular and spring boot. Currently, static resource is configured using properties:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/web-template/,classpath:/static/
```

Before I use bean config:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/web-template/")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
```

A simple log trying directly access a js file.

```
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-4] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7e25c043
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher    : Checking match of request : '/app/view/service.js'; against '/app/.*'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /app/view/service.js has an empty filter list
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-4] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7e25c043
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7e25c043
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher    : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/app/.*'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher    : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/assets/.*'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.700 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 1 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 2 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 3 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 4 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout'
2016-04-29 15:02:37.715 DEBUG 7372 --- [http-nio-9082-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Logging out user 'null' and transferring to logout destination
```

Any idea about this weird behaviour?

Edit:
I was using spring-io-platform version 2.0.1-RELEASE and updated to 2.0.3 trying to solve this issue.

Edit: Configuration converted to Java Config with no solution.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ImportResource("classpath:application-context-ui-security.xml")
@Profile(DEFAULT_PROFILE)
protected static class SecurityUIApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private MyAuthenticationFilter myAuthenticationFilter;

    @Inject 
    private MyTokenFilter myTokenFilter;

    @Inject
    private DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultSuccessHandler;

    @Inject
    private DefaultAccessDeniedHandler defaultAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Resource
    private DefaultLogoutHandler defaultLogoutHandler;

    @Inject
    private DefaultLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint defaultLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web.ignoring().regexMatchers("/app/.*", "/assets/.*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(defaultAccessDeniedHandler)
            .authenticationEntryPoint(defaultLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(myAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(myTokenFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html**","/services/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and().formLogin()
            .failureHandler(defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(defaultSuccessHandler)
        .and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(defaultLogoutHandler)
            .deleteCookies("user")
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            ;
    }

}
```

I still importing a xml because I need to import framework xml and there are a abstract bean to override But is just a properties.

Comment: why not revert to ant expression approach with the correct expression which would be
    `<security:http pattern="/app/**" security="none" />`
    `<security:http pattern="/assets/**" security="none" />`

Comment: I already tried. Same problem. Now I am converting all configuration to Java config. I hope to see anything else.

Comment: Workaround the problem putting a logic to match patterns in my custom filter in order to avoid the external dependency. The static continue passing for all security filters, unfortunately